# How to change a date to time from today in python?

Tags: python, pandas, date, time

I have a column in a pandas dataframe filled with dates (in the format YYYY-MM-DD). 
I would like to write a code that would automatically change the values from time from today. That is if the date is 07/08/2019 it would automatically change that into the number one (because in one year), and if the date was in 6 months it would change into 0.5 (years). I need it to be precise to the day exactly as a fraction of the year, so like we could get number with a few decimal.

Would you kindly know how to do that ?

Comment: Please explain in more detail how `07/08/2019` equals `1` and `07/02/2020` equals `0.5`. The logic isn't exactly obvious.

Comment: do you search for the difference of the months?

Comment: What's the value of ``07/08/2020``? Is it ``0``, ``1`` or ``2``? Why is ``07/08/2019`` assigned ``1`` and not ``0``? Is there a reason why you want the fraction of year(s) instead of the number days? What about leap years? Can differences in them reach ``1.0027397260273974`` or just ``1``?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly you need to parse the date string into a date object using [strptime](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.strptime)
Then get the difference between that and now. Convert it into days and divide by a year

Something like:

```
 import datetime

 then = datetime.datetime.strptime('2019-09-07', "%Y-%m-%d").date()
 now = datetime.datetime.date().now()

 print (then - now).days / 365.0
```

Comment: Of course that leaves open questions about what to do with leap years, or if the date is > 1 year in the future…

Comment: Very true! But as aways with dates, times and timezones, having a solution is only the start of the problems :) This should get OP off the ground though

Comment: Thank you! @ChrisCharles So now I have something like that:
    then = datetime.datetime.strptime(str, "%Y-%m-%d").date()
    today = date.today() 
and I wanted to know if there is any ways to put it as a function to apply it to an entire pd column, I've tried something like that but not sure what to put as an argument: